# How two switch between multiple divs when div content should refresh every 5 seconds?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with 2 (or more) buttons and divs.
After clicking button 1, an partial view should load to "DivPartialView_1" and refresh every 5 seconds. When user clicks button 2 "DivPartialView_1" should hide and another partial view content should load to "DivPartialView_2" and also refresh every 5 seconds. My problem is, that the both divs are visible afte clicking button 2, because the first content refresh (ajax) is still ongoing.

My scripts looks like this:

```
function loadPartialView_1(){
        $('#DivPartialView_1').show();
        $('#DivPartialView_2').hide();

        $('#DivPartialView_1').load('/PartialViewData_1’);
    }

function loadPartialView_2(){
    $('#DivPartialView_1').hide();
    $('#DivPartialView_2').show();

    $('#DivPartialView_2').load('/PartialViewData_2’);
}


$('#btnShowPartial_1').click(function () {
    function RefreshPartial_1(){
        //this will wait 3 seconds and then fire the load partial function
        setTimeout(function(){
            loadPartialView_1();
            //recall this function so that it will continue to loop
            RefreshPartial_1();
        }, 5000);
    }
    //initialize the loop
    RefreshPartial_1();
});

$('#btnShowPartial_2').click(function () {
    function RefreshPartial_2(){
        //this will wait 3 seconds and then fire the load partial function
        setTimeout(function(){
            loadPartialView_2();
            //recall this function so that it will continue to loop
            RefreshPartial_2();
        }, 5000);
    }
    //initialize the loop
    RefreshPartial_2();
});
```

Where could be the problem or what could be a better solution?

Thanks